# Issues about thread stopped or not in progressDialog in Android with AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I have a code as following, and the thing is every time I cancel the dialog, InterruptException occurs and the `cancel` method doesn't really work. As I shows below, I print the state of `cancel` in the `onPostExecute` method, it is a false instead of true. Before adding `isRunning` parameter, obviously the thread was still running in the background. Although `isRunning` does stop the thread( the `onPostExecute` method was executed), I want to know why the exception happened and why I still got a `false` in the `isCanceled` method. Thanks!

```
public void startDownload(View view){
    dialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    final Downloader downloader = new Downloader(this, dialog);
    downloader.execute(0);
    dialog.setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
            downloader.cancel(true);
        }
    });
}
```

```
public class Downloader extends AsyncTask<Integer, Integer, String> {
private Context context;
private PowerManager.WakeLock wakeLock;
private ProgressDialog dialog;
public boolean isRunning = true;

public Downloader(Context context, ProgressDialog dialog) {
    this.context = context;
    this.dialog = dialog;
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    wakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK,
            getClass().getName());
    wakeLock.acquire();

    dialog.setMessage("Downloading...");
    dialog.setIndeterminate(true);
    dialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
    dialog.setCancelable(false);
    dialog.setButton(ProgressDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, "Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            isRunning = false;
        }
    });
    dialog.show();
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(Integer[] params) {
    int count = params[0];
    while(count<100 && isRunning){
        publishProgress(count);
        try{
            count++;
            System.out.println(count);
            Thread.sleep(200);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
    super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    dialog.setIndeterminate(false);
    dialog.setMax(100);
    dialog.setProgress(values[0]);
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
    super.onPostExecute(s);
    wakeLock.release();
    dialog.dismiss();
    if (s != null)
        Toast.makeText(context,"Download error: "+ s, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    else
        Toast.makeText(context,"File downloaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    System.out.println(isCancelled());
}
```

}

Comment: Can you remove `Thread.sleep(200);` and try again?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're not executing another AsyncTask, or start this one in parallel, using `.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR)` instead of `.execute()`. Otherwise, if you're already running another AsyncTask in background this other one will not run until that last one finishes.

On the other hand, try not to track AsyncTask lifecycle status with a custom boolean, to do so, use `isCancelled()` to check stuff at runtime or break any loop and if required, override the AsyncTask's `onCancelled()` method to implement any functionality you may need at that point.

Don't forget to check the reference: [AsyncTask - Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#cancel%28boolean%29).